# Importing data from JSON

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm facing an issue importing a JSON file using the apoc.load.json procedure.

The expected relationship I'm trying to capture:
University --child--> Class --child--> Student

Output:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `value` not defined (line 1, column 8 (offset: 7))
"UNWIND value.university AS university"
```

Here is the performed command sequence:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("FILE:///C:/tmp/input.json") YIELD value

UNWIND value.university AS university
UNWIND university.class AS class
UNWIND class.student AS student
MERGE (u:UniversityCategory {name:university.name})
MERGE (c:ClassCategory {name:class.name})
MERGE (s:StudentCategory {instr:student.name})
ON CREATE SET i.ID = instructions.ID
ON CREATE SET i.GPA = instructions.GPA
MERGE (u)-[:CHILD]->(c)
MERGE (c)-[:CHILD]->(s)
```

Here is the JSON file structure:

```
{
    "university": [{
        "name": "universityA",
        "class": [{
                "name": "class_1",
                "student": [{
                        "name": "student_1",
                        "ID": "1234",
                        "GPA": "3.8"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "student_2",
                        "ID": "12345",
                        "GPA": "3.4"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "class_2",
                "student": [{
                    "name": "student_3",
                    "ID": "14",
                    "GPA": "3.0"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

My apoc.load.json command appears to work because I see the structured JSON file in the browser window.  The next steps are suspect but I think I'm close to defining the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my issue.

The commands I expressed above are all correct but the load.apoc.json command has to be run in the SAME query as the rest versus sequentially.